# How to activate/enable code suggestions in oxygen for aspectj?

Tags: eclipse, aspectj, ajdt

At work, some teammates uses the Neon version for Eclipse and STS plugin, or STS officially packed from spring.io. I just installed the Oxygen version with STS, and even test the packed STS.

But for me, the AspectJ code suggestions are not working. I tried installing the last development builds from eclipse ajdt support [page](https://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/) (the one with Eclipse 4.7 support, and also the 4.7 support with AspectJ 9). Although I have the option in the IDE to show and use the AspectJ Editor, I cannot get the proper code suggestions with Ctrl+Space sub-menu.

I tried resetting the workspace, cleaning the projects, building with maven... and all that stuff. Nothing works.

Did anyone deal with this problem and succeed??

Moreover, with the Neon package (Eclipse 4.6), there's no problem, so the projects are fine.

Comment: Have you tried plain vanilla Oxygen.2 for Java Devs installation and AJDT from http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/47/dev/update? It works nicely for me including Ctrl+Space code suggestions. I have _not_ installed any STS stuff.

Comment: Yeah! I tried with Eclipse for Java and for Java EE versions. Nothing at all. Also, I'm on MAC. And I tried with Neon versions, and nothing. Finally, I did some research and check the JDT Weaving. If I go to Preferences > JDT Weaving > Reindex now, and restart Eclipse, I get all methods in _aj_ files.

Comment: Aha, so it was the configuration rather than anything else. Glad you solved it.